# Printing Bitmap to raw socket 9100 Android

Tags: android, printing

I've managed to print normal txt to a printer so i know i can communicate with the printer but i cannot print and image, it prints funny characters.

```
public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); 
return buffer.array();
```

}

```
private void doPrintJob() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
Socket objSocket = new Socket("10.10.0.37", 9100);
OutputStream  objOutputStream;
objOutputStream = objSocket.getOutputStream();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
objOutputStream.write(getBytesFromBitmap(image));

objOutputStream.close();
objSocket.close();
```

}

Now i know a few of you may say i need to send a PCL or PS file - i dont know how & how would i make my Bitmap into a PS/PCl file and how would i send it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you find a solution for your problem ?

Comment: Two years and still nothing? I desperately need an answer to this question - or are there maybe some other options to use a LAN printer? Other than simple socket? I know printing images from Android on LAN printers is possible... Somehow...

Comment: @NoHarmDan its soo long ago I can't even remember which project this was for....

Comment: @Wil_Ryan well that's a shame..